# Luks UEFI Boot not asking for password?

Tags: arch-linux, encryption, uefi, luks

I've setup an encrypted UEFI-Booting Arch installation<sup>1</sup>.
Why am I not asked for the phrase on booting?

Remark: If I change the name **crypto** in `/etc/crypttab` to e.g. **encryptedBOOT** I am
required to enter a password on boot, though I can enter anything and get to
login without a hassle.

lsblk

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0   250M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 118.9G  0 part  
  └─crypto      254:0    0 118.9G  0 crypt 
    ├─Arch-swap 254:1    0   512M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─Arch-root 254:2    0 118.4G  0 lvm   /
```

dmesg | grep -i "error\|warn\|fail"

```
[    1.052685] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM
[    2.340204] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    9.002142] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.PMIO) (20181213/utaddress-213)
[    9.004065] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.LPIO) (20181213/utaddress-213)
[    9.004107] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.LPIO) (20181213/utaddress-213)
[    9.004185] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC.LPIO) (20181213/utaddress-213)
[    9.455380] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    9.455385] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[  175.019957] random: 5 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

df -h

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
run                    1.9G  756K  1.9G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/Arch-root  117G  1.8G  109G   2% /
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2              243M   76M  155M  33% /boot
/dev/sda1               99M  125K   99M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                  383M     0  383M   0% /run/user/0
```

cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3

```
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          4
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           16459d28-76a6-40c4-b96d-090cf2f411fc
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2i
    Time cost:  4
    Memory:     608808
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       10 23 09 25 cd 08 38 47 e4 56 27 2f e9 ab d6 96 
                61 ed 32 9a 6a f7 36 a6 12 d3 1e 8b 02 4b cf f3 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha512
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
  1: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2i
    Time cost:  4
    Memory:     605120
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       2e df 79 1d 5b c8 2d d6 89 c3 d0 7c a7 47 a7 e1 
                d4 63 4e 42 38 51 0d 12 4d a8 cd dd 09 d0 cb 1b 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:290816 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha512
    Iterations: 125307
    Salt:       11 8b 07 aa 78 49 32 4e bf a7 8b b0 8a 29 89 d6 
                ff 5d 90 3f a4 68 ee f6 c5 71 7a 44 10 7e 0d 1f 
    Digest:     d4 42 ae 00 6c 03 d1 ab b9 37 62 4a ce be 93 dd 20 d4 71 6e 03 7b 92 40 b4 8d ff 54 3c 97 72 21 
                3b 86 fe 5e ec 18 79 2f 1f 3c 19 d8 20 94 44 a1 06 b7 44 30 a5 75 4d 5b f8 a1 cc 03 c6 a9 98 0f
```

/etc/default/grub

```
# GRUB boot loader configuration

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap"

# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"

# Uncomment to enable booting from LUKS encrypted devices
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# Uncomment to enable Hidden Menu, and optionally hide the timeout count
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

# Uncomment to use basic console
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
#GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-blue/black"
#GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/blue"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/wallpaper"
#GRUB_THEME="/path/to/gfxtheme"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# Uncomment to make GRUB remember the last selection. This requires to
# set 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' above.
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvmid/YPm8Dv-HYiA-CyfU-yV0y-aVH0-n917-W3uEwd/GyClul-dXdo-8gyf-j0N4-RwTG-wFVt-3KH4fO'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/YPm8Dv-HYiA-CyfU-yV0y-aVH0-n917-W3uEwd/GyClul-dXdo-8gyf-j0N4-RwTG-wFVt-3KH4fO'  46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,gpt2' --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/Arch-root rw cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Arch Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b' {
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,gpt2' --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/Arch-root rw cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-fallback-46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,gpt2' --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/Arch-root rw cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 29 18:13 16459d28-76a6-40c4-b96d-090cf2f411fc -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 29 18:13 46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 29 18:13 4ef43d75-a4c7-4ef0-84d9-66a968578ff1 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 29 18:13 7AE8-13D9 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Mar 29 18:44 9671-F6FA -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 29 18:13 b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0 -> ../../sda2
```

/etc/fstab

```
# /dev/mapper/Arch-root
UUID=46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/sda2
UUID=b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0   /boot       ext2        rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl   0 2

# /dev/sda1
UUID=7AE8-13D9          /boot/efi   vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/mapper/Arch-swap
UUID=4ef43d75-a4c7-4ef0-84d9-66a968578ff1   none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

/etc/crypttab

```
# Configuration for encrypted block devices.
# See crypttab(5) for details.

# NOTE: Do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up
#       beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf).

# <name>       <device>                                     <password>              <options>
# home         UUID=b8ad5c18-f445-495d-9095-c9ec4f9d2f37    /etc/mypassword1
# data1        /dev/sda3                                    /etc/mypassword2
# data2        /dev/sda5                                    /etc/cryptfs.key
# swap         /dev/sdx4                                    /dev/urandom            swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
# vol          /dev/sdb7                                    none
crypto  UUID=b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0    none                    luks,timeout=180
```

/etc/mkinitcpio.conf

```
# Configuration for encrypted block devices.
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
MODULES=()

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=()

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=(/crypto_keyfile.bin)

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS=(base)
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block keymap encrypt lvm2 resume filesystems keyboard fsck)

# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
```

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> https://gist.github.com/HardenedArray/31915e3d73a4ae45adc0efa9ba458b07

Comment: the only reliable thing I understand is that UUID=b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0 <=> /dev/sda2 (not /dev/sda3 as you probably wanted). Also since /boot is not encrypted, it looks to me that there's no need of any special GRUB support. I'm a bit baffled for the remaining part (where is retrieved the passphrase?)

Answer (score 2):

A late answer, but perhaps it helps someone else:

You have a UEFI system. So the bootloader gets loaded from e.g. `/boot/efi/EFI/ArchLinux/grubx64.efi` by the firmware. The firmware finds the `/boot/efi` partition (also known as EFI System Partition, or ESP for short) using its PARTUUID which is stored in the UEFI NVRAM boot variables, viewable with `efibootmgr -v`. The firmware might alternatively find the ESP by its partition type. The ESP must be unencrypted, or else the firmware won't be able to read the bootloader.

Once the bootloader has started, it will read its own configuration file. The location of the configuration file varies between distributions, but a common scheme places a minimal `grub.cfg` file on the ESP, in the same directory as the `grubx64.efi` file. That mini-`grub.cfg` will only contain the lines required to find and read the "real" `grub.cfg` from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

(An alternative method would be to embed the location of the real `grub.cfg` into the `grubx64.efi` on installation... but that would invalidate the signature of the `grubx64.efi`, so that won't work on systems that use Secure Boot.)

In your case, the `/boot/efi/EFI/ArchLinux/grub.cfg` would probably be something like this:

```
search.fs_uuid b558ecc3-2d22-481b-91eb-26cdc2e86cf0 root
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Note that the `root` here **does not refer to the Linux root filesystem** but to the root of the filesystem that contains the GRUB configuration file, i.e. the `/boot` filesystem. That's why the first line mentions the UUID of your `/dev/sda2` partition.

In your case, `/dev/sda2` is your non-encrypted `/boot`. The mini-configuration tells GRUB to find it by UUID, read the real GRUB configuration file from `<root of /boot filesystem>/grub/grub.cfg`, which will be the familiar `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` when the OS is running and `/boot` is mounted. But at boot time, GRUB only accesses one filesystem at a time.

Your real `grub.cfg` includes this bit to use the graphical mode and load the `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2` from the Linux root filesystem:

```
set root='lvmid/YPm8Dv-HYiA-CyfU-yV0y-aVH0-n917-W3uEwd/GyClul-dXdo-8gyf-j0N4-RwTG-wFVt-3KH4fO'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/YPm8Dv-HYiA-CyfU-yV0y-aVH0-n917-W3uEwd/GyClul-dXdo-8gyf-j0N4-RwTG-wFVt-3KH4fO'  46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 46268152-ba54-4ecf-ad04-b381c8da1c2b
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
```

With your current encrypted root filesystem, this will not work, because those hinted UUIDs would require GRUB to already be able to access the encrypted root filesystem, but so far it hasn't been told to look for an encrypted LUKS volume. GRUB will just fall back to using the firmware-provided display mode and font, but may display an error message about failing to load `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2`.

A modern GRUB could read files from a LUKS-encrypted filesystem, but it would need to see a `cryptomount -u 16459d28-76a6-40c4-b96d-090cf2f411fc` command first: that would cause GRUB to prompt for the LUKS passphrase and make the encrypted volume accessible to GRUB (allowing GRUB to search for filesystems and LVM logical volumes inside the encrypted volume after that).

Since `unicode.pf2` contains nothing secret, it might be easier to copy it to `/boot/grub/` and set `GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/unicode.pf2` in `/etc/default/grub`, so `grub-mkconfig` will know to add commands to load the font from there instead of trying to access the root filesystem.

With your current configuration, this should eliminate the need for GRUB to understand the LUKS encryption: it will just load the kernel and initramfs from the non-encrypted `/boot` filesystem and pass a set of parameters to the kernel. The initramfs file will then include a script to ask for the encryption passphrase and unlock the encryption for Linux use.

Your current kernel parameters are visible in `grub.cfg` as:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/mapper/Arch-root rw cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap quiet
```

and it's determined by these lines in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap"
```

While this works as long as the order of disk devices doesn't change, using UUIDs is the current recommended way, as it's more robust against e.g. USB sticks accidentally left plugged in when booting. So you should change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID:16459d28-76a6-40c4-b96d-090cf2f411fc:crypto resume=/dev/mapper/Arch-swap"
```

Note that the UUID here is the UUID displayed by the `cryptsetup luksDump`, not the UUID of the filesystem inside the encrypted volume, as the filesystem UUID won't be available until the encryption is unlocked first.

(This will be true even if you used encrypted `/boot` since GRUB cannot pass the cryptsetup unlock state to the kernel: the kernel will need to unlock the encryption all over again even if GRUB already did it once. To avoid the need to enter the encryption passphrase once for GRUB and again for initramfs, you could use a key file stored within the initramfs for unlocking the root filesystem... but if you do this, then the initramfs **absolutely must not** be stored on a non-encrypted partition, as access to the initramfs file that contains the root filesystem key file will give access to the root filesystem for free.)

The `cryptdevice=` option is essentially the equivalent of the `/etc/crypttab` line for unlocking the LUKS volume containing the root filesystem within initramfs: if that takes care of unlocking your only LUKS volume, then you might technically not need `/etc/crypttab` at all, but for the sake of completeness, your `/etc/crypttab` line should be:

```
crypto UUID=16459d28-76a6-40c4-b96d-090cf2f411fc none luks,timeout=180
```

Here, the UUID is also the UUID displayed by the `cryptsetup luksDump` command. The purpose of `/etc/crypttab` is to identify how each encrypted volume should be presented in unlocked form, and exactly how the unlocking should happen. In this case, the line indicates the encrypted volume `/dev/sda3` (identified by the UUID of the encrypted volume, which is all that's available to identify it by content until it's successfully unlocked - you can't use the UUIDs of the filesystem or LVM held within the encrypted volume here), that it is a LUKS volume and there are no automatic sources for the encryption passphrase, so a passphrase prompt must be presented. This is done by the `encrypt` hook script within the initramfs file.

Once the passphrase has been entered, the initramfs will automatically probe for LVM volume groups within the encrypted volume, and will activate the `Arch` VG as soon as it finds it. All this is done by the `lvm2` hook script in initramfs. After that, `/dev/mapper/Arch-root` and `/dev/mapper/Arch-swap` will become accessible, and initramfs can proceed with activating the swap (and optionally checking for a hibernation image within it, and resuming it if there is one) and mounting the root filesystem.

---

Your current `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` contains the line:

```
FILES=(/crypto_keyfile.bin)
```

This could be used with the encrypted `/boot` to identify the key file that will unlock any LUKS volumes on the system. In other words, with encrypted `/boot`, you would only manually unlock the encryption of `/boot` for GRUB, and then GRUB would load from there the initramfs file containing the key file that will allow initramfs to unlock the root filesystem (or indeed any number of encrypted volumes) without need to input any further passphrases. **But this will also make the security of the initramfs file critical to the security of your system**.

If `/boot` is not encrypted, then I don't see the purpose of this file, as there is no reference to it in your `/etc/crypttab` nor anywhere else. If this file exists and contains a valid key for unlocking your LUKS volume without entering a passphrase, it will be available within the un-encrypted initramfs file **and so your disk encryption can be unlocked without knowing the passphrase** once the attacker inspects the initramfs file and notices the `crypto_keyfile.bin` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a crypttab to make this work.

The first problem I see is your GRUB config needs to be fixed. Don't use a hard path like /dev/sdX, use a UUID instead and you need to specify the root path for the mapped crypto device.

```
cryptdevice=UUID=device-UUID:root root=/dev/mapper/root
```

The [Arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_the_boot_loader) is the go-to source with way more information than I can post here but if you need more detailed information then ask away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a proper `/etc/crypttab` file.
Also, remember to add your mount points to the `/etc/fstab`.

`crypttab` should contain something like this:

```
targetname    physicalpartition    none
```

For instance:

```
targetData   /dev/sdb3    none
```

Where `targetData` is a name you create for the target that will be used by `/dev/mapper`.